# FormatMessage(): Is there a way to avoid flag FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER with FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM?

Tags: winapi

This question is about `FormatMessage()` with `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` and `GetLastError()`.  The goal is *where possible* to use stack allocation and avoid heap allocation.

Some Win32 API functions provide a way to query for the size.  If the output buffer is too small (including `NULL`), the return value will be the expected buffer size.  Example: `GetTempPath2()`.

When calling `FormatMessage()` with `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` and `GetLastError()`, this does not seem possible.

One idea: Call `FormatMessage()` with a 8196 char/wchar_t stack-allocated buffer.  On failure, call `FormatMessage()` again with flag `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`.  It seems hard to believe that the system error message can be longer 8196 chars!

I tried to do some research about maximum length Win32 system error, but I could not find anything reliable.  To be clear, I assume that Win32 error messages can be in any supported national language.  For example, when comparing UK/English vs Germany/German, German is probably much longer.

Comment: Hmm. Your 'guess' at 8196 bytes is a bit shy. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage), the maximum buffer size is 128K bytes (for system-allocated) or 64K bytes, for a local buffer passed by the caller. But *either* of those values is some hell of an error message!

Comment: But, I agree that a 'probe' version of the call (e.g. with `lpBuffer` set to `NULL`) would be nice. The function, as it is, *does* return the number of `TCHAR`s written.

Comment: `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` or `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` here unrelated. function really not return required size. so we can use or `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` or some fixed size buffer (usually 0x100 bytes always enough ). if this fail wil error - buffer too small - you can use `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` on second call or increment buffer size. but you already know this. so in what is question ?

Comment: To avoid heap allocation for *FormatMessage* should not be a task of optimization.

Comment: @AdrianMole I had to read that doc many times to realise there are broadly four different use cases for that function with system error.  (1) System alloc or user-provided buffer?  (2) `sprintf(lpSource, Arguments)` or not?  Weirdly, if system alloc, it can return 128K `TCHARS` (remember: `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4`), else user buffer can only store 64K `TCHARS`.  Absolutely bizarre design to me.  The answer from @DJm00n below links to DotNet core source (C'ish source code!) that _appears_ to show that the max system error message length is 512 `TCHARS`.

Comment: @RbMm: One part confuses me about your comment.  I didn't mention `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE`.  Did part of your comment get lost or deleted?  Second, I asked the question to clarify best technique.  The official docs are so insanely complex that I want to make sure that I wasn't missing something "obvious" more experience Win32 programmers... or, if there is undocumented behaviour (plenty of that in Win32 API!).

Comment: Note that, on Windows in C and C++, `sizeof(wchar_t)` is **2 bytes**.

Comment: @kevinarpe - i say that flag `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` unrelated to your question. system alloc exactly, how many needs for string.  in most case- the best and simpliest - use `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER `

Comment: @AdrianMole You are right about `sizeof(wchar_t)`!  I was thinking about Linux x86-64.  A lot of my Win32 coding is done on Linux/Wine, so I get confused sometimes. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core uses `4096 * sizeof(WCHAR)` buffer on stack for `FormatMessageW` call. And...thats it.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3b63eb1346f1ddbc921374a5108d025662fb5ffd/src/coreclr/utilcode/posterror.cpp#L264-L265

Comment: This is perfect, because that code is written by "insiders".  Looking deeper, `FormatRuntimeErrorVA()` is called next, which calls `UtilLoadStringRC()` with a `wchar_t` buffer of length 512.  To my eyes, that is the true max.  Do you agree?  (To be clear, I am *only* using `FormatMessage()` to retrieve text for system error.  I don't use it for additional formatting.)  Ref: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3b63eb1346f1ddbc921374a5108d025662fb5ffd/src/coreclr/utilcode/posterror.cpp#L123

Comment: @kevinarpe .NET Core isn't written with inside knowledge. The implementation merely illustrates one thing: If .NET (Core) has to choose between correctness and features, and those properties are in conflict, the authors will choose features. The value `4096` had been put there, without any prior research. You can tell by looking at the comments.

Answer (score 2):

> One idea: Call `FormatMessage()` with a 8196 char/wchar_t stack-allocated buffer. On failure, call `FormatMessage()` again with flag `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`.

Unfortunately, that is exactly what you need to do, if you want to use a stack buffer.  Unlike most other Win32 APIs, `FormatMessage()` will not tell you the required size of the buffer it needs.

> It seems hard to believe that the system error message can be longer 8196 chars!

In fact, the documentation clearly states that error messages can be as large as 128K! Although, user-provided buffers cannot be larger than 64K.

Comment: You are right about 128K `TCHARs`, but that includes `sprintf(lpSource, Arguments)` formatting.  Here, I am only using `FormatMessage()` to convert system error code to message text.  I'm not using the formatting functionality.  I should have made that more clear in my question.